# how to read data from spreadsheet with .xlsm format in perl?

Tags: perl

I want read data  from spreadsheet ,which is .xlsm format.I am unable to access it.its showing blank while access the data .so i want how to access .xlsm format in perl.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::read qw(ReadData);

my $book = ReadData ('C:\Perl64\bin\sample.xlsm');
   foreach my $line(1..1000) {
           my @rows =Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow($book->[0],"$line");
           print "@rows"; 
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to provide as much information as possible, as well as some code examples of the  things you 've already tried. Otherwise, you ll not get help.

Comment: What have you tried? What module, which version?

Comment: Active perl 5.24.2

Comment: @Anand — What **module**? You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: sir i want sample code to read macro enable .xlsm file format in perl?

Comment: @Anand — You have some code already. Show it to us. Explain the problem with it. Get help fixing your code. Don't throw it away and ask us to show you how to do it from scratch.

Comment: Please delete the code comment

Answer (score 0):

seems the module you used doesn't work on xlsm files

consider using `Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML` instead ;)

http://search.cpan.org/~jandrew/Spreadsheet-Reader-ExcelXML/lib/Spreadsheet/Reader/ExcelXML.pm

also beware, you should use `push` instead of `@rows = ...`, this way, you won't overwrite `@rows` at each `for` iteration

when you try to open a file you should add `or die "error message";` at the end of the open, this way you will see if the file opened correctly

`my $book = ReadData ('C:\Perl64\bin\sample.xlsm') or die "error while opening the file";` triggers the error with your example code